# there is already an open DataReader associated with this connection which must be closed first vb.net mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i'm having an error

there is already an open DataReader associated with this connection which must be closed first.

this is my code.
can you please help me???
thank you

```
    MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; port=3307; user id = root; password = 1234; database = mcs;"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader


    If cmbxyear.Text = "NURSERY" Then


        MySqlConnection.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = " select student_no from mcs.fullpayment_nursery where student_no = '" & txtstudent_no.Text & "'"
        Dim Command As New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConnection)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader
        If query = txtstudent_no.Text Then

            MessageBox.Show("YOU DON'T HAVE REMAINING BALANCE")
            MySqlConnection.Close()


        Else

            Dim query1 As String
            query1 = " select student_balance from mcs.installmentpayment_nursery where student_no = '" & txtstudent_no.Text & "'"
            Dim Command1 As New MySqlCommand(query1, MySqlConnection)
            READER = Command.ExecuteReader
            READER.Read()
            txtstudentbalance.Text = READER(0)


            MessageBox.Show("Student Balance Generated")
            MySqlConnection.Close()


        End If
```

Comment: The error message speaks for itself.  You can't open a second data reader on a connection where one is already open.  That said, your code doesn't make sense.  You need to re-evaluate what it is that you're trying to achieve and write sensible code to do it.

Comment: Your `If` statement (`If query = txtstudent_no.Text Then`) will never be true, so that code will never get executed.  Also your code is open to sql injection attacks.